# how to limit each rows in total column sql?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, subquery

I have a column like this

```
total  name   gender 
2      Mike   male
2      Dion   male 
2.     Shinta female
2      Sarah  female
10     Pio    male
10     Olive  female
10     Steve  male
80     Yuri   female
80     Kio    male. 
80     Doni   male
80     Dora   female
80     Nobi   male. 
80     Hiou   male
```

how to limit each total it to be just 2 person only ?? 
I got that table from  created View and Join it, and got that table, but if I limit, it only limit the first row on the top, but not each total 
I really want to get each total 2 with 2 person, and total 10 get 2 person, and 80 get 2 person, 
is that possible???

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or SQLite?

Comment: sqlite , sorry:D

Answer (score 3):

You can try using `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by total order by null) as rn
from tablename
)A where rn<=2
```

Comment: Fast gun +1.  You beat Gordon by 6 seconds.

Comment: what the meaning A after) ??

Comment: I guess `order by null` will throw error. `order by (SELECT NULL)` will be work

Comment: @poppop, A means temp table name of that sub query, usually is written as 'as A'.

Answer (score 0):

Window functions would often be used for this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by total order by total) as seqnum
      from tempview t  -- or whatever your logic is here
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2;
```

Of course, window functions are only available in the most recent versions of SQLite.

In older versions of SQLite this is painful, but this should work:

```
select t.*
from tempview t
where t.name in (select t2.name
                 from tempview t2
                 where t2.total = t.total
                 limit 2
                );
```

This assumes that the names are not repeated for a given `total`.

Comment: what the meaning t.* ??

Comment: @poppop . . . It selects all columns from the subquery or table that has been assigned the `t` table alias.

Comment: my sqlite3 is the latest I think

Comment: @poppop . . . Window functions were added in SQLite 3.25.0.  If you are using that release or later, then the `row_number()` version should work.

Comment: I already created that above table as VIEW and the name table is tempView, and then I copy your command, still syntax error near "(": syntax error

Comment: you are correct, how to upgrade the newest version  of sqlite3?

Comment: I did upgrade by npm, but still use old version:(